# Web Scraping with Python3

Tags: python-3.x

This code is about web scraping. The problem is when i run this code a get some error whis is "ValueError: Length of passed values is 6, index implies 7 ". How can i fix this error. 
the values langth is but index length is 7 that's why error occurs.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Game_of_Thrones_episodes"
page=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')

table=soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable plainrowheaders wikiepisodetable'}).tbody

rows=table.find_all('tr')

columns=[v.text.replace('\u200a[20]','') for v in rows[0].find_all('th')]

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for record in range(1,len(rows)):
    tds=rows[record].find_all('td')

    if len(tds)==4:
        values=[tds[0].text,tds[1].text,tds[2].text,tds[3].text]
    else:
        values=[td.text for td in tds]

    df=df.append(pd.Series(values,index=columns),ignore_index=True)

    print(df)
```

Hare is the error in line number 25.The error is given below.

````
  File "good.py", line 25, in <module>
    df=df.append(pd.Series(values,index=columns),ignore_index=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 300, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length of passed values is 6, index implies 7```

how can i solve this problem:::::
````

Answer (score 1):

Did a quick google search and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54754976/2408212). Seems like you are trying refer to an empty dataframe.

I haven't worked with Numpy and hence, I don't know what a dataframe is and what it's supposed to do, but I went and looked at your code and seems like `pd.Series(values,index=columns)` expects the length of `values` and `columns` to be equal.

I checked your code and saw that the lengths aren't same. Length of `values` is 6, while length of `columns` is 7. Hence, the error.

Check out [REPL HERE](https://repl.it/@Xonshiz/QuarrelsomeValuableScientist).
I've put few print statements, enable them and check the values. Also, I added a check if length match or not...when I added this, seems like your code went through just fine.

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but until someones replies, I'd suggest that you look into your `values` and `columns`